# How can I downsample a dataframe consisting of numerical as well as categorical columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame consisting of EEG signals from 64 channels and 3 categorical columns and timestamp column. I want to down sample the numerical columns and eliminate the corresponding categorical values. I used pandas.resample but it converts my categorical values to NaN. I also used `signal.decimate` but it also throws type error on categorical values.

Any suggestions on what I can do to achieve the desired result?

The structure of DataFrame is like this:

```py
headers = list(range(64)) #Numerical columns to be down sampled

headers.append('ActualChar', 'PossibleCharCol', 'ResultLabel' , TimeSequence') #Categorical columns just to be eliminated without any change in value.
```

Dataframe:
[image: Structure of dataframe]
Complete data frame consists of 371740 rows

The data can be accessed from http://www.bbci.de/competition/ii/#datasets under dataset IIb.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help to provide a [mcve] including sample input data and expected output, and code for what you've tried so far, so that we can better understand what you mean by "eliminate the corresponding categorical values".

Comment: I have added the dataset structure. Basically I just want to downsample the whole dataframe without affecting the few columns of my dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to generate random integers.

```
n = np.random.randint(0,300,size=40)
```

then do, `df.iloc[n,:]`

Comment: but I don't want to generate random no. Also I want to downsample my categorical values along with my numerical values